# Book of Explanations of Mathematics' Formulas

Tags: reference-request, book-recommendation

Most mathematics' formula books I have seen so far tell you the formula for this or that or just list them one after the other.

E.g. on **the Curved Surface of a Cone**, the formula for the angle of a sector derived from the curved surface is equal to 360 times Base radius divided by Slant height of cone.

**Why? Why is it so?**  This is not explained. So on formula after formula.  But I want to know **WHY?**...the WHY of a formula.

Is there a book in which a mathematician has patiently explained the derivation of all or most mathematical formulas at least up to Advanced Level Mathematics Pure or Applied please?

Can someone recommend a book I can buy on the Why of Formulas? Thank you!

Comment: The "why"s are usually found in the books on subject areas, rather than in the collections of formulas, so I suspect you won't get a satisfactory answer. But I hope I'm wrong: it's a good question.

Comment: The formula books likely have references at the back (or at the end of each major topic), at least I would think so. However, all mine (CRC handbook, Schaum's Outline formula book, Barnes and Noble formula book, etc.) are at home and I'm at work right now, so I can't confirm this.

Comment: We look up a formulary handbook when we apply some facts without deriving from scratch or find something you've forgotten.  In other words, you're supposed to have some mathematical backgrounds.  For explanation, it's better to borrow or look up   textbooks or problem-and-solution references on the relevant topics in College/University libraries.

Answer (score 1):

No such book has been written.  Amusingly, the mathematician Paul Erdős often referred to "The Book" in which God keeps the most elegant proof of each mathematical theorem.  During a lecture in 1985, Erdős said, "You don't have to believe in God, but you should believe in The Book."